# I need help understanding Frege's definition of number

Tags: logic, definition, predicate-logic, philosophy, foundations

I have really been trying to understand Frege's definition of a number or at least gain a strong intuition of it. However, my attempts have not been fruitful. If someone could help me it would be much appreciated. I will write his definition down explicitly, then give write down a little bit of what he writes around this definition.

Number - The content of a statement of number is an assertion about a concept.

[source : *The Foundations of Arithmetic*, §55, Engl.transl. page 67]

Here is what he writes before and immediately after stating his definition:

Immediately Before: While looking at one and the same external phenomenon I can say with equal truth both "It is a copse" and "It is five trees," or both "Here are four companies" and "Here are 500 men." Now what changes here from one judgement to the other is neither any individual object, nor the whole, the agglomeration of them, but rather my terminology. But that is itself only a sign that one concept has been substituted for another.

[source : *The Foundations of Arithmetic*, §46, Engl.transl. page 59]

Immediately After: This is perhaps clearest with the number $0$. If I say "Venus has $0$ moons", there simply does not exist any moon oor agglomeration of moons for anything to be asseted of; but what happens is that a property is assigned to the concept "moon of Venus", namely that of including nothing under it. If I say "the King's carriage is drawn by four hourses", then I assign the number four to the concept "horse that draws the King's carriage"

[source : *The Foundations of Arithmetic*, §46, Engl.transl. page 59]

Edit: For those who are more inclined to reading logic. On part 2.5 of the following link it explains what Frege was doing. Unfortunately, I'm having difficulties understanding this as well. I have been exposed to some first order logic, but no second order logic whatsoever. I am not sure if that is necessary though.

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#NatNum

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help!

Comment: This is not a math question. Does not belong to this website.

Comment: If I asked if this was a math question, then this would not be a math question because it would involve philosophy. However, one might take care in claiming that this is not a math question since it most definitely involves defining a mathematical object or structure. That being said, I would rather not hold this debate with you. Instead, I would like to wait for some positive responses from those who are versed in foundationalism. Thank You.

Comment: "Of the following link" has no link that follows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Alex! Just fixed it.

Comment: @Valentino Your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th paragraphs are not saying anything in any clear language. If you want to talk about vague terms that nobody really understands then you should discuss it on a philosophy board. If you want to see the standard way of defining natural numbers then I suggest to learn set theory, it is defined as an the minimal inductive set. If you want to ask about logic, then stick to that specifically.

Comment: @Nicolas I know just fine the "standard" way of defining natural numbers. You must be great at parties. Anyways, it seems Mauro was able to understand and answered my question, so thanks for all your great advice and feedback. I'll definately be sure to use it in the future to avoid any type of firing squad.

Comment: @ Nicolas Also, I just checked what was defined by the scope of the community as an acceptable type of question, and "History and development of mathematics" and "Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems" are definately on the list which can be found here http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Last time I checked number is a mathematical concept, and Frege's work on defining number is part of the history and development of mathematics.

Comment: @Valentino Stop being so defensive. You can ask about "history" and "development" and "foundations" and "numbers". But your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th paragraph was incomprehensible. All you had to say was, "can somebody help me understand this concept", that was it. You could have saved all that typing. And yes, numbers are part of mathematics. But your vague paragraphs are not, mathematics consists of clarity not vagueness.

Comment: @ Nicolas Those are not my vague paragraphs. Those are Frege's. So, if you find that the father of foundationalism is incomprehensible and vague, then that's an opinion you are entitled to. However, I was simply giving the context from which the definition was written.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki,  Frege, once said : "Every good mathematician is at least half a philosopher, and every good philosopher is at least half a mathematician." :)

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki, You're actually a *formalist* ;)

Comment: @Valentino I looked at the link you provided and word-searched some of the things you wrote in your paragraphs. None of them came up, so it is incorrect to say those are Frege's words. Maybe you are paraphrasing him then, okay, but whatever you are doing it is vague and unclear. This is why it does not belong to this website.

Comment: @ Nicolas It is not paraphrased whatsoever Nicolas. Those are his words exactly in section 46 of The Foundations of Arithmetic.

Comment: "The content of a statement of number is an assertion about a concept?" I would be worried if you *could* make sense of that! If you want to do mathematics, Peano's axioms seem to be all the definition of numbers that you will need. Thankfully, definitions like Frege's here are now nothing more than historical curiosities of a bygone age.

Comment: @FardadPouran Just because Frege said this, we should not consider it to be true. I disagree in particular the second part although the first part is not much better.

Comment: @Peter , I'm completely changed! I totally disagree to Frege at the moment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Some hints*

The context of Frege's assertion is his analysis of the "number assertions"; see :

- *Die Grundlagen der Arithmetik: eine logisch-mathematische Untersuchung über den Begriff der Zahl* (1884), translated as [The Foundations of Arithmetic: A logico-mathematical enquiry into the concept of number](https://books.google.it/books?id=z0KtOtNYMEQC&printsec=frontcover) by J.L. Austin (1950).

Roughly speaking, Frege denies that when we use number-words in natural language assertions we express a property of objects; i.e. when I say "my hands are white" I'm asserting that each of my hands *is white*, while when I'm saying  "I have two hands", I'm not asserting that each of my hands "*is two*".

Thus, Frege's conclusion is that the "number-words" are like adjectives for *concepts*, i.e. they express a property of a concept.

*Example* : there are two satellites of Mars : Phobos and Deimos. When we say "Mars has two satellites", we express the fact that the concept "satellite of Mars" is *instantiated* by two objects.

In modern expression, we have that :

> $\exists x \exists y [Sat_M(x) \land Sat_M(y) \land x \ne y \land \forall z(Sat_M(z) \to (z=x \lor z=y))]$.

This is also clear from the analysis of the number $0$ :

> "if I say "Venus has $0$ moons", there simply does not exist any moon or agglomeration of moons for anything to be asseted of; but what happens is that a property is assigned to the concept "moon of Venus", namely that of including nothing under it."

i.e.

> $\lnot \exists x Moon_V(x)$.

This point has fundamental consequences in Frege's view : numbers are akin to quantifiers.

In Frege's terminology, both number and quantifiers are *second-level* concepts, i.e. they are concepts that express a property of *first-level* concepts (like the concept : "moon of Venus", i.e. concepts "applying" to *objects*).

This fact can be highlighted by the "formal" analysis; we have that Phobos satisfy the concept "Satellite of Mars", i.e. $Sat_M(Phobos)$ holds.

In Frege's terminology, the *object* Phobos "falls under" the *concept* "Satellite of Mars".

The concept "Satellite of Mars" is *instantiated*, i.e. there are objects that "fall under" it. Thus the second-level concept "existence" applies to the first-level concept "Satellite of Mars", i.e. $\exists x Sat_M(x)$ holds.

---

We can "formalize" Frege's view (in a "philological" inaccurate way) as follows :

1) assume the universal quantifier $\forall$ as *primitive*;

2) define the existential quantifier $\exists$ as usual, as : $\lnot \forall \lnot$;

3) introduce the "numerical" quantifiers :

i) $\exists^0$ defined through : $\lnot \exists Fx$ : "there are **no** $F$'s"

ii) $\exists^1$ defined as the "usual" $\exists !$, i.e. as $\exists x Fx \land \forall y (Fy \to x=y)$ : "there is (exactly) **one** $F$"

iii) $\exists^2$ as $\exists x \exists y (Fx \land Fy \land x \ne y \land \forall z(Fz \to z=x \lor z=y))$ : "there are **two** $F$'s"

and so on.

These "numerical" quantifiers are the formal counterpart of "number-words".

---

You can see :

- Kevin Klement, [Frege’s Changing Conception of Number](http://people.umass.edu/klement/fnum.pdf), Theoria (2012).

Comment: Thank you so much Mauro for positively contributing to my question. This clears up a lot. I was having a really difficult time trying to find a place that explained this in plain english! This answer was beautiful.

Comment: I have one more question that is somewhat relevant that I have been trying to figure out for awhile. Is there a difference between concepts and predicates? If so, what is it? Also, a more subtle question that I've been wondering for awhile is how do normal sets that we are used to in math differ from predicates in logic? Thanks again.

Comment: @Valentino - in modern logic, a *predicate* $P$ is a symbol of the (*first order*) language; its "meaning" or "reference" in an interpretation $I$ is the subset $P^I$ of $I$ of all the "objects" $d \in I$ such that $d \in P^I$. This is the meaning of the semantical clause : $I \vDash P(d)$ **iff** $d \in P^I$. Thus, according to Frege, the predicate (expression of the language) "__ is a Man" (i.e. $Man(x)$) has a two-fold meaning : the *concept* $Humanity$ and its *extension* : the set $Men$ of all men.

Answer (score -1):

Frege develops his answer in several stages throughout the Grundlagen.

The first step (which you are asking about) is ascertaining what it is that number-statements are about.

For Frege the world divided into objects and concepts. An object is a specific entity that might be describable in one of several ways. A concept is like a way of thinking about or describing things. So ‘blue’ is a concept, as is ‘moons of the planet Jupiter’. Any object could be blue or could not; it could be a moon of Jupiter or not.

In the sections you refer to, Frege points out that you cannot point to single object and say it is (or has) the number x. You can talk about a concept and say it has x instantiations. So you could say ‘Jupiter has 4 moons’ which is similar to saying ‘the concept “moon of Jupiter” is instantiated by 4 entities’.

Frege’s point is that statements involving numbers are always being predicated of concepts not of objects.

Things can seem a little more confusing when you hit sections 55-57. There he makes it clear that he believes that numbers are objects and not concepts and that can seem confusing.

But the key is to distinguish number-statements from numbers. Statements that involve numbers, when used in real-world (ie not mathematical applications) such statements are always about concepts. But the number word itself is never a concept.

Frege points out that a) a number word often is used as an object (eg in mathematical statements like 1+1=2, or ‘the number 5 is a prime number’
b) number words never appear as complete predicates/concepts. You can never describe a concept with just the number 4, you will always have to incorporate the number-term into a large statement to turn it into a predicate (so you can’t say ‘the car is 4’ but you can say ‘the car has 4 doors’)
c) statements involving number can always be re-parsed so that the number term is separated from the predicate sentence into a distinct object that is being referred to. Eg ‘Jupiter has 4 moons’ is logically equivalent to ‘the number of objects that satisfy the predicate “moon of Jupiter” is 4’.

So for Frege numbers are abstract objects. Therefore any translation if arithmetic into logic (his logicist project to provide a foundation for mathematics) must find a way to define numbers as objects, which means to be able to specify conditions under which something can be recognised as a number or not without appeal to human intuition. They are also the type of objects that, outside of mathematical contexts, will be used in second order statements, ie those that assert a concept of another concept (usually how many objects instantiate the concept).

Frege ends up by using ‘extensions of [certain] concepts׳ since extensions (think of sets of things) are (logically) objects. They are things you could talk about and potentially they could have more than one concept they instantiate.

To avoid circularity (defining numbers in terms of numbers) Frege uses the notion of ‘equinumerosity’ (an equal number) which sounds like it uses numbers but it doesn’t. The reason is that I don’t need numbers to know if something is equinumerous. Even if I don’t know how many knives or forks there are on the table, if I see that every plate has one of each then I see that they can be matched up therefore they are equinumerous.

So the number 0 is the abstract object of things that instantiate the concept ‘equinumerous with “not being identical with itself” ‘
So the steps are:
(i) there is a concept “not being identical with itself”
(ii) there are no objects that instantiate that concept. This is an example of ‘nothing’ that is generated out of logical notions and no intuitive or ‘in the world’ entities or concepts. It therefore belongs to the realm of logic and maths. In that realm there are concepts that have no objects that could ever instantiate them.
(iii) now we have a concept ‘equinumerous with the concept “not identical with itself” ‘
(iv) so what is/are the object/s that instantiate that? You can either say it the object we call 0.

Now that we have a (what Frege thought was a) purely logical way to define zero, we can also define the number one in a similar way.
(i) the concept “identical with 0”
(ii) clearly there is only one object there, 0. Anything identical with an object is the same object!
(iii) now we can talk about the concept ‘equinumerous with to the concept “identical with 0” ‘ that is a concept.
(iv) now we talk about the instantiation of that concept, or the ‘extension of the concept…’ and the object that instantiates it is the number 1.

More generally Frege defines the successor relation such that if any number is defined its successor can also be defined, in a similar way.
(i) assuming we defined an object that is the number n, we can then talk about the concept ‘identical with 0, or 1, or… , or n’
(ii) the set of objects that will instantiate that will be precisely the numbers from 0 to n ie the integers up to and including n.
(iii) then we employ the concept ‘equinumerous to the concept “identical with…” ‘ that will be the concept of being in one-to-one correspondence with the aforementioned set. Note the set of numbers up to n includes zero so it has n+1 members.
(iv) the ‘extension of that concept’ is the object that is the number n+1.

So by the time he has finished, each number can be put back into a sentence where it is part of a ‘concept phrase’ that predicates another concept.

Eg the sentence
‘The set of integers from 0 to n’ defines an object much as ‘the Planet Jupiter’ is an object.
‘Equinumerous with the set of integers from 0 to n’ is a concept that relates to the object, much as ‘moons of the planet Jupiter’ does.
Then the following are equivalent:
‘The object that is the extension of the concept “equinumerous with…” is the number 4’
Equivalent to
‘The number of things “equinumerous with…” is 4’
Equivalent to
‘There are 4 members of the set ‘equinumerous…”’

Again in the Jupiter analogy
‘The object that is the extension of the concept “moons of Jupiter” is the number 4’
Equivalent to ‘the number of things that are moons of Jupiter is 4’ (or the number of moons of Jupiter is 4’)
Equivalent to ‘There are 4 moons of Jupiter’

Which is why Frege set it up that way in the first place.