# Why did Frege need to use Courses-of-Value in his number Concept

Tags: logic, math-history, philosophy

I am studying Frege's work and Russell's Paradox. I can't understand why did Frege need to use Courses-of-Value in his number Concept, wouldn't it be enough to state "Any concept F is equal to Zero, if there is a bijective relation f between F and the function diferent from itself" or in his ideography:
[Concept of Zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYffx.png)

Thank you very much

Francisco Pedrosa

Comment: Very few people on MSE will know Frege's Begriffschrift (those that do may enjoy [this image](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10214640436187397&set=pb.1317497734.-2207520000.1537483071.&type=3&theater)). Please translate Frege's statement into modern notation.

Comment: $F$ is a function (I think...) and thus in $F=0$ we have ti read $0$ as a function also ?

Comment: Is the bottom part of your formula : $(\forall b) [ \lnot (b=b) \to \lnot (\forall a) (Fa \to \lnot f(a,b))]$ ?

Comment: Similarly, the top part is : $\lnot (\forall a)[Fa \to \lnot (\forall b)(\lnot (b=b) \to \lnot f(a,b))]$ ?

Comment: See laso the post [Frege and Value-Range](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45993/frege-and-value-range/45994#45994) for discussion about *Wertverlauf*.

Comment: Related post : [Understanding Frege's definition of number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226398/i-need-help-understanding-freges-definition-of-number)

Comment: @RobArthan in modern notation it is: Ψ(F,¬(b=b))→(F =0)
Where the relation Ψ is the bijection relation:
Ψ(F,G) = (∃Φ){[∀a][F(a)→(∃b)(G(b) ∧ Φ(a,b))]∧[∀b][G(b)→(∃a)(F(a) ∧ Φ(a,b))]} 
But, as Begriffsschrift has no Exists symbol, I was using the equivalence
¬[(∀a)(F(a) →¬B)] = (∃a)(F(a)→B) (Im not sure if its right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

[Frege's course-of-value](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#CouExtProMatFou) of a *function* (or *concept*) is something very akin to the *extension* of a concept : the collection of objects satisfying the concept.

And see [Frege's definition of number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Foundations_of_Arithmetic#Frege's_definition_of_a_number) :

> Frege argues that numbers are objects and assert something about a concept. Frege defines numbers as extensions of concepts. 'The number of $F$'s' is defined as the extension of the concept $G$ *is a concept that is equinumerous to* $F$. The concept in question leads to an equivalence class of all concepts that have the number of $F$ (including $F$). Frege defines $0$ as the extension of the concept being non self-identical. So, the number of this concept is the extension of the concept of all concepts that have no objects falling under them. The number $1$ is the extension of being identical with $0$.

Thus, starting from the condition : $¬∃xFx$, expressing the fact that nothing falls under $F$ (in modern notation : the *extension* of $F$ is the empty set) he defines the *number* $0$.

In order to achieve this, Frege uses the machiney if *course-of-values* and related axiom (see [Basic Law V](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#S2)).

For details, see [Frege's Theorem and Foundations for Arithmetic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/).